# Batch File to move tv shows using special characters?

Tags: batch-file

Trying to figure out an efficient way to sort tv shows from download folder.  I 
know this is far from the best solution but it's within my comfort zone :)

Anyway, I want the batch file to search the file name and move it to the correct folder

My TV Show folder structure is   TV > Show Name > Season > Files

So for example if I have a file named   Archer.S01E01.mkv  I'd like it moved to TV > Archer > Season 1  etc.  I've created a couple variables %source% and %dest% to cut down the amount of space needed as shown below:

```
::Show: Archer

move %source%*archer*S01* %dest%archer\"season 1"\

move %source%*archer*S02* %dest%archer\"season 2"\

move %source%*archer*S03* %dest%archer\"season 3"\

move %source%*archer*S04* %dest%archer\"season 4"\

move %source%*archer*S05* %dest%archer\"season 5"\

move %source%*archer*S06* %dest%archer\"season 6"\

Is there a way to use an array to move the files to the correct folders? Something along the lines of:

move %source%*archer*S0[1-6]* %dest%archer\"season [1-6]"\  ?
```

I know that particular example won't work, I'm guessing I'll need some sort of loop?  But for the life of me I have no idea how to make that work.

It would be even better if the loop would go through the files and match part of the string to the show so I wouldn't have to create a command for each and every tv show I have in my library.

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming all files share the same template of "[ShowName].S[SeasonNumber]E[EpisodeNumber].mkv", then the following should create all folders as needed, and move the files. Please note - this is untested.

```
@echo off
set "source=yourSourceFolder"
set "dest=yourDestinationFolder"
pushd "%source%"
for /f "delims=" %%F in (
  'dir /b /a-d *.mkv ^| findstr /rix "[^.]*\.s[0-9]*e[0-9]*\.mkv"'
) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=." %%A in ("%%F") do (
  for /f "delims=SsEe0" %%S in ("%%B") do (
    if not exist "%dest%\%%A\season %%S\" md "%dest%\%%A\season %%S\"
    move "%%F" "%dest%\%%A\season %%S\" >nul
  )
)
```

Comment: It worked!  Unfortunately not all files are in that exact format of "[ShowName].S[SeasonNumber]E[EpisodeNumber].mkv".  I'll give a few examples below of a few different shows.

Archer.2009.S05E12.HDTV.x264-KILLERS.mkv
Boardwalk.Empire.S01E01.720p.HDTV.x264.mkv
breaking.bad.s01e01.720p.bluray.x264-reward.mkv
Elementary.S01E01.720p.HDTV.X264-DIMENSION.mkv

They all contain the same basic information, but not necessarily in the same order.  It ALWAYS begins with the show name, but after that I only need it to read the S##E## part.

Thank you so much for your help so far.

Answer (score 0):

Another way (in place of season it will just create the subdirectorys SO1, SO2,...SO9 in the directory named with the SHOWNAME (Archer in your example) :

```
@echo off
SET "SOURCE=YOUR\SOURCE PATH"
SET "DEST=YOUR\DESTINATION PATH"

SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
FOR /F "TOKENS=1,2* DELIMS=." %%A IN ('DIR  /B/A-D "%SOURCE%\*.MKV"') DO (
SET $DEST=%%B
SET $DEST=!$DEST:~0,3!
IF NOT EXIST "%DEST%\%%A" MD "%DEST%\%%A"
IF NOT EXIST "%DEST%\%%A\!$DEST!" MD "%DEST%\%%A\!$DEST!"
MOVE "%SOURCE%\%%A.%%B.%%C" "%DEST%\%%A\!$DEST!"
)
```